Excel Slicer move to another tab (Slicer with condition)
I am using slicer but I want to add like hyperlink function. I tried lots of formula but none work.
here the problem I want to solve using slicer + hyperlink (any alternative no problem)
Sheet1



Column A
Column B




Customer
Cell 2


Client
Cell 3



Sheet2



Column A
Column B




A1
B1


A2
B2



what I want below is if the slicer is in or equal to customer I want it to move directly to sheet2 A1 or sheet3 A1 (if I add another sheet tab)
hoping to find answer here,
Thank you

Having too small information, I created the solution for you:

A table contains the names you mentioned in the first column, hyperlinks in the second column, and the formula =ROW() in the third column.
Slicer "Role" is created for the first column of the table.
C4 =SUBTOTAL(9,[Switch])

Sheet1 code:
Dim SelRow As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  If SelRow <> [C4] And [C4] < 4 Then
    SelRow = [C4]
    Cells([C4], 2).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
  End If
End Sub

Selecting a value on the slider, the related hyperlink is followed.
There many options for this solution depending on your needs.
